# Get all unique keys and values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have several collection in mongodb. The example of structure of data present in mongodb is as follows:

```
{
    u'_id': ObjectId('581453c6aeddbf0f04fa017b'), 
    u'pdpData': {u'taxEntry': {u'taxPercentage': 5}, u'fashionType': u'Core'}
},
{
    u'_id': ObjectId('581453c7aeddbf0f04fa017c'), 
    u'pdpData': {u'taxEntry': {u'taxPercentage': 5}, u'fashionType': u'Fashion'},
    u'catalogAddDate': 1467297611
}
```

I want the union of all the key and value in a csv format.
example of the result is as follows:

```
objectID,                  pdpdata.taxEntry.taxPercentage,   pdpdat.taxEntry.fashionType,   pdpdata.catalogAddDate
581453c6aeddbf0f04fa017b,  5,                                core,                          NA
581453c7aeddbf0f04fa017c,  5,                                Fashion,                       1467297611
```

I have tried several method but unfortunately I am unable to get the column names in the required format

```
mapper = Code(""" function() {for (var key in this) { emit(key,null);}}""")
reducer = Code("""function(key, stuff) { return null; }""")

distinctThingFields = db.women.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out ={'inline' : 1}, full_response = True)
print distinctThingFields
```

here I am only getting the column values as

```
objectID , pdpdata
```

not the inner key

Comment: Are your documents in different collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> several collection in mongodb. The example of structure of data present in mongodb is as follows

Assuming that you mean several documents rather than several collections, you could utilise [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

Using PyMongo, based on your data examples, you could group by `objectId`, `taxPercentage` and `fashionType` as below:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$group':
       {'_id':
         {'objectId':"$_id",
          'taxPercentage':"$pdpData.taxEntry.taxPercentage",
          'fashionType':"$pdpData.fashionType"
         }
       }
     }]
cursor = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Iterating the cursor should return you :

```
{u'_id': {u'taxPercentage': 5.0, u'objectId': ObjectId('...'), u'fashionType': u'Fashion'}}
{u'_id': {u'taxPercentage': 5.0, u'objectId': ObjectId('...'), u'fashionType': u'Core'}}
```

You can then utilise Python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to export to CSV.

If you have these documents spanning across multiple collections, and:

a) The documents have the same data structure: Generally you should have same structured documents in the same collection. See also [Data Modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for more info.

b) The documents have different data structure: You can run aggregation per collections, then aggregating the result in your Python script (client side). If this is a frequently used query/reporting, you should reconsider your data structure.